# Nginx not working on port 80

Tags: http, nginx, configuration

I have a node.js server running on `localhost:1337`. I have made a nginx site file in `sites_enabled`. If I go to url `admin.tvchatter.cn:1337`, it is working, but if I go to url `admin.tvchatter.cn`, the page sitll shows "Welcome to nginx!". It seems the `listen 80` is not working. the file contents are:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.tvchatter.cn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/admin.tvchatter.cn.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/admin.tvchatter.cn.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1k;
    gzip_buffers 16 64k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Welcome to nginx!"` mean, nginx is working on port 80, but it didnot redirect traffic from port 80 to port 1337

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `root` clause, by default it contain value: `/var/www/html/index.html` hence you see default nginx page. My config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` to find:

```
proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
```

to see nginx use proxy_pass to other port.

if yes, disable it.

Comment: There is only this config file in sites-enabled.

Comment: try add it `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` after `proxy_set_header` line

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the proxy was working only if I was using another port like 90

In fact, I was importing all the conf files like this in my */etc/nginx/nginx.conf*:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

But my file was conflicting with existing ones in this folder. I changed it to this and it worked:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/frontend.conf;
```